# Run local Python script from webpage using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, python, php, ajax

as the title suggests, I have a problem with **JS && PHP && Python**.

***What I want to do is following:***

I have a webpage running using Apache2 web server (page code is saved on this machine), which works fine. On this page there is a button, which, when pressed, sends Ajax request to run my PHP file located on my web server (source code is located on the same machine as my page code) [(Ubuntu 22 btw)].

**JavaScript funtion for button press:**

```
function runScript() {
    runTime = document.config.time.value;
    repeats = document.config.repeats.value;
    performFWUpd = document.config.fwperform.value;
    systemType = document.config.system.value;
    phoneA = document.config.phoneAtype.value;
    phoneB = document.config.phoneBtype.value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ip_of_webserver_pc/callScript.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                runTime:runTime,
                repeats:repeats,
                performFWUpd:performFWUpd,
                systemType:systemType,
                phoneA:phoneA,
                phoneB:phoneB
              },
              success: function(data) {
              },
              error: function() {
                console.log('Error occured');
              }
    });
}
```

So I basically just get some user-given values from input-form and then passing them as arguments to my **PHP script, which is following**:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['runTime']) && isset($_POST['repeats']) && 
       isset($_POST['performFWUpd']) &&
       isset($_POST['systemType']) && isset($_POST['phoneA']) && isset($_POST['phoneB'])) {
          exec("var/www/python_script/main.py $_POST['runTime'] $_POST['repeats'] $_POST['performFWUpd'] $_POST['systemType'] $_POST['phoneA'] $_POST['phoneB'])");
    }
?>
```

The Python script itself is located at the same machine as all previous files.
And then (finally), Python script should be called with given parameters from PHP file:

```
import sys
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Get parameters from script call arguments
  execTime = sys.argv[1]
  numOfRepeats = sys.argv[2]
  performFWUpdate = sys.argv[3]
  targetSystem = sys.argv[4]
  phone1 = sys.argv[5]
  phone2 = sys.argv[6]
  run()
```

At the moment, when I press the button (which should trigger JS function -> PHP -> Python) on my web page, nothing happens apart from refreshing the page and change of the URL:

**Before call:** *http://ip_of_webserver_pc*

**After button pressed and page refresh:** *http://ip_of_webserver_pc/?time=a&repeats=b&fwperform=c&system=d&phoneAtype=e&phoneBtype=f*

Can somebody please help me understand what is going on and how to fix it? :D

Comment: If the page refreshes when you click the button you probably use the wrong button type (should be `type="button"`. For your call to your python script try using the complete path to your python binary to execute your script, something like `exec("/usr/bin/python3 var/www/python_script/main.py ...`

Comment: It is possible to make a webserver run python directly too, btw

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code?